# Tag stats for Apache take ages to load, throw 500

Tags: bug, status-completed

Trying to load the stats for the `Apache` tag

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=apache&sort=stats&pagesize=50

takes ages for me (up to 30 seconds) and then ends in a `Oops! Something Bad Happened`.

It doesn't do this for any other tag, although they all seem to take longer than usual.

Comment: It's failing for me with [jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=stats&tagnames=jquery), too.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to bad query plans getting stored in SQL cache.

[How do I remove a specific bad plan from the SQL Server query cache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/91285/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-bad-plan-from-the-sql-server-query-cache)

It's also related to `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`, which gets blocked / negated in any SQL containing full text queries.

Comment: yep, I ran `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL') WITH MARK_IN_USE_FOR_REMOVAL;` and now it's fine.